# Math environment Minion Pro

Tags: math-mode, symbols, minionpro

I am using minion pro for my report and  could like to change the math symbols in text environment.Currently the math symbols in text (section no, subsection no, figure no) appears as marked black in the figure:
[image]

Is it possible to get math symbols in text as marked with red color? I tried using

`\usepackage[textlf,mathlf,minionint]{MinionPro}`

which gives me an error:`texify:pdflatex.exe falied to create pdf file.`

Can some one help me?

Edited---

Here is my complete typeset

```
\documentclass[12pt,vi,twoside]{mitthesis}
\input{Body/header}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
%\fontencoding{LY1}\fontfamily{ACaslonPro}\mdweight

\input{Body/cover}
\pagestyle{plain}
\input{Body/contents}

%now start the fancy headings
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\addtolength{\headheight}{\baselineskip}
%add a nice little line underneath the heading
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.6pt}

\input{Body/chap1}
\input{Body/chap2}
\input{Body/chap3}
\input{Body/chap4}
\input{Body/chap5}

\clearpage
%\appendix
%\addcontentsline{toc}{part}{Appendix}
%\input{Body/appa}
%\input{Body/biblio.tex}
%\input{Body/index.tex}
\end{document}
```

Here are the information in my header.tex file

```
\usepackage[mathlf,minionint]{MinionPro}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
%\usepackage{MyriadPro}
%\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{Minion-LF}
 \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    %(Not Sure whether to include this package or not)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathtools}      % fix amslatex, provide \smashoperator, \cramped, \adjustlimits
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage{program}
\usepackage{newlfont}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{txfont}
\usepackage{table}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{program}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}  
\usepackage{eucal}      
\usepackage{ulem} 
\normalem % normal emph w/ ulem
\usepackage[numbers,square,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage[pdftex,plainpages=false,breaklinks=true,colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue,citecolor=green,linkcolor=blue,bookmarks=true,
bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=1,pdfstartview=Fit,pdfview=Fit,linktocpage=true,bookmarksnumbered=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage{hypernat}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{eucal}
\usepackage{emptypage} 

% Symbols used by the authors
    \DeclareMathOperator{\suffix}{suffix}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\prefix}{prefix}
    \DeclareMathOperator{\prob}{Pr}
    \DeclareSymbolFont{AMSb}{U}{msb}{m}{n}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\N}{\mathbin}{AMSb}{"4E}
  \DeclareMathSymbol{\realNums}{\mathbin}{AMSb}{"52}


%this defines the basic headers and footer
% styles when we use the 'fancyhdr' styles
%\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\itshape\footnotesize\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\itshape\footnotesize\rightmark}}
%\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\itshape\footnotesize\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\itshape\footnotesize\thepage}}
%\lhead[\fancyplain{}\bfseries\thepage]{\fancyplain{}\bfseries\rightmark}
%\rhead[\fancyplain{}\bfseries\leftmark]{\fancyplain{}\bfseries\thepage}
%\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{0.5\marginparsep}
\addtolength{\headwidth}{0.5\marginparwidth}
%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
%\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize\thepage}]{\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize\rightmark}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize\leftmark}]{\fancyplain{}{\footnotesize\thepage}}
\cfoot{}
\cfoot{}
```

Comment: Can you provide a MWE to show what else you are doing?

Comment: Michael, can you please elaborate more, what all other information you need?

Comment: It means providing the minimal code needed to get you example. Then its easier to understand errors and modify if necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I am new user here. Do, I paste my complete type-setting here?

Comment: Just add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I cannot paste enter typeset here.i.e. from  \documentclass{...} ........ \end{document}

Comment: Please add this to the end of your posting, you can simply edit it for this purpose.

Comment: @Michael I didn't understand what you said!

Comment: You can add the code that Sujiro mentioned into you initial post. Under the post you have a button called "edit" which can be used to edit the posting and add the code.

Comment: I edited my post by adding my typeset. It looks quite ugly,but please forgive me as I am new user here.

Comment: You can add four spaces in front of each code line. It will then be typeset using a monospaced font, which makes it a lot easier to read.

Comment: Or you highlight the text and use the `CTRL + k`command afterwards. This enters the four spaces on the marked text.

Comment: Is my typeset readable now ?

Comment: Any solution to my question?

Comment: Can somebody suggest if it's possible ?